# Apache Superset: Viewing embedded dashboard through single login after applying RLS in the API through Django apps doesn't work as intended

Tags: dashboard, embedding, apache-superset, row-level-security

Context: Our Apache Superset dashboard is embedded in Django apps

Goals: We want our user to have limited view of a dashboard that is limited by Row Level Security(RLS) that is incorporated in the API.

1. Filter supposed to be applied on the dashboard to specific user logged in via API using RLS within the API.
2. However, when accessing the dashboard via API (with the RLS defined in it), the dashboard appears to be unfiltered as intended.
3. In our case, the RLS in the API didn't apply the username filter as intended to the dashboard.
4. Based on the information given, we seek the community kind advice on how to make it work as intended.

Below is our API script to generate guest token and filter information of the user by incorporating rls in it.

```py
import requests
SUPRSET_API_URL = 'http://test.example.com:8088/api/v1'
data = {
    "password": "admin",
    "provider": "db",
    "refresh": "true",
    "username": "admin"
    }

payload = {
    "resources": [
        {
        "id": "11",
        "type": "dashboard"
        }
    ],
    "rls":[
        {
            "clause": "initid in (SELECT DISTINCT initid FROM reference.rls_bajet23 WHERE ia_username = {{current_username()}} or pm_username = {{current_username()}})",
            "dataset": 26
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "username": "admin"
    }
    }
 
response = requests.post(f'{SUPRSET_API_URL}/security/login', json=data)
api_url_for_guesttoken = f'{SUPRSET_API_URL}/security/guest_token'
response_token = requests.post(api_url_for_guesttoken , json=payload, headers={'Authorization':f"Bearer {access_token}"})
print(response_token.json().get('token'))
```